# MATLAB: strmatch vs strcmp

Tags: matlab

If I'm using a char string as the needle and a cell array of chars as the haysack, would the following achieve the same results *every* time? I'm looking at their documentations, but I don't see anything that would suggest otherwise. I wanted to check with SO's community as well.

Basically,

```
k = strmatch('abc', cellArray, 'exact');

k2 = find(strcmp('abc', cellArray));
```

where `cellArray` is an Nx1 cell array of chars and it has 'abc' values at arbitrary indices. For example, if `cellArray` has `abc` at indices 10, 20, and 30. Then would the following be true *everytime* for any `cellArray`?

```
k = [10 20 30];

k2 = [10 20 30];
```

Also, if both methods return the same answers, when would you use `strmatch` over `strcmp` in this kind of search scenario (looking for a char string in a cell array of same data type)? `strmatch` is extremely slow, if anyone is wondering why I'm even asking.

Answer (score 3):

No, the results will be different. The function `strmatch` returns a vector of *indexes* where the cell array (haystack) matches the string (needle):

```
>> arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'};
>> strmatch('a', arr, 'exact')
ans =
    1
    4
```

The `strcmp` function returns a logical vector, with `1`s where the haystack matches and `0`s where it doesn't match:

```
>> strcmp('a', arr)
ans =
    1   0   0   1   0
```

On the other hand, the expression `find(strcmp('a', arr))` is equivalent to `strmatch('a', arr, 'exact')`.

Comment: There was a typo in my post. I added `find(...)` a few minutes ago. Silly mistake.

Comment: Anyway, have any idea why you'd use `strmatch` over `strcmp` in a string search?

Answer (score 2):

`strmatch` is not recommended. Use `strncmp` or `validatestring` instead. `strmatch` will be removed from a future version of matlab. 
*Warning given in `Matlab 2017 a`.